# MacMini transmit rate stuck at 11, every other device can connect at full 54Mbit/s?

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, 802.11g

I have a MacMini circa 2007 that's getting very low transmit rates via wifi, 8-11. I have other devices that are getting full 54, including a MacBook Air. With everything else off, the MacMini doesn't want to seem to go any faster. Since it has been previously connected to ethernet its entire life, I was wondering if there were some settings I can change to speed up the connection. Option-clicking the network icon gives this read out:

PHY Mode: 802.11g
Channel: 1 (2.4 Ghz)
Security: WPA2 Personal
RSSI: -73
Transmit Rate: 11

My new MacBook Air has the following readout:

PHY Mode: 802.11n
Channel: 1 (2.4 Ghz)
Security: WPA2 Personal
RSSI: -66
Transmit Rate: 79

Both have full bars and the wireless router is in the same room to eliminate any obstructions from the equation.

Could the MacMini be connecting at an older protocol, like 802.11b and be reporting erroneously that it is connected at 802.11g? This would explain why I haven't seen a transmit rate above 11. Any further trouble shooting I can try before buying a new USB 802.11n device?

The WiFi router is a DLink DIR-615. I can see other devices, and none, even the other g connected devices, are getting below 30-40 MBit/s. What's going on here?

Comment: looks like a distance issue to me...just my 2 cents.  take the laptop right next to the AP to find out the truth.  802.11n can support transmit channel bonding to get better speed even when connecting to a 802.11g network that is too far away

Comment: Every single Mac mini model in existence is 802.11b/g. So that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Distance / interference was an issue! Moved it about 2 feet closer and it shot up to full 54. Strange, there was a stereo near it, perhaps that was adding to it? Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own answer so this can be removed from the "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance / interference was an issue! Moved it about 2 feet closer and it shot up to full 54. Strange, there was a stereo near it, perhaps that was adding to it? Thanks!